# Tricky date string to parse in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

`Fri Nov 10 05:45:36 +0000 2017`

I've tried both moment and chrono-node.  Both are getting stumped by this date format.

Any suggestions to get a valid UTC date?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly did you try with Moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @CertainPerformance's answer, the problem with your code, if you try with MomentJS is that it is not a standard ISO date string. Parsing it directly without specifying format will result in incorrect result and a warning like this:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.
```

To mitigate, always pass the format to MomentJS constructor like this:

```js
const inputStr = "Fri Nov 10 05:45:36 +0000 2017"
const mom = moment(inputStr, 'ddd MMM D HH:mm:ss ZZ YYYY');
console.log(mom.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you out:

```js
var date = new Date("Fri Nov 10 05:45:36 +0000 2017").toISOString();
date = date.split("T")[0];
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment works just fine:

```js
const inputStr = "Fri Nov 10 05:45:36 +0000 2017"
const mom = moment(inputStr, 'ddd MMM D HH:mm:ss ZZ YYYY');
console.log(mom.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to make that `HH:mm:ss` since there's no AM/PM to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference between 2 items of each array which is returned by the code that I have written to process the date strings of the form you have provided.

Finally you can have a look at the full code example given.

> In first case, both are same.
>
> In second case, both are different.

```
console.log(dateArr1); // [ '2017-11-10', '2017-11-10' ];
console.log(dateArr2); // [ '2018-05-15', '2018-05-14' ];
```

> So it's clear our UTC conversion is working fine.

Please have a look at the below code example and try to understand. It is simple.

> **Note»** All the comments inside function are for `inputDateStr`: **"Fri Nov 10 05:45:36 +0000 2017"**

```
// All the comments inside function are for 
// inputDateStr: "Fri Nov 10 05:45:36 +0000 2017"
function getMyUTCDate(inputDateStr)
{
    var inputDateString = inputDateStr;
    var date = new Date(inputDateString);
    var dateArr = []; // To store 2 dates, simple one & full UTC one

    console.log(date); // 2017-11-10T05:45:36.000Z

    // ............... SIMPLE EXAMPLE ..........................
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes()
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();

    console.log(year);  // 2017
    console.log(month); // 10
    console.log(day);   // 10
    console.log(hours); // 11
    console.log(minutes); // 15
    console.log(seconds); // 36

    utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds));
    utcDateString = utcDate.toUTCString();
    console.log(utcDate);       // 2017-11-10T11:15:36.000Z
    console.log(utcDateString); // Fri, 10 Nov 2017 11:15:36 GMT
    var dt1 = utcDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
    dateArr.push(dt1)
    console.log(dt1); // 2017-11-10

    // .................. FULL UTC EXAMPLE ..........................
    var utcYear = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var utcMonth = date.getUTCMonth();
    var utcDay = date.getUTCDate();
    var utcHours = date.getUTCHours();
    var utcMinutes = date.getUTCMinutes()
    var utcSeconds = date.getUTCSeconds();

    console.log(utcYear);   // 2017
    console.log(utcMonth);  // 10
    console.log(utcDay);    // 10
    console.log(utcHours);  // 5
    console.log(utcMinutes);// 45
    console.log(utcSeconds);// 36

    var utcDate2 = new Date(Date.UTC(utcYear, utcMonth, utcDay, utcHours, utcMinutes, utcSeconds));
    var utcDateString2 = utcDate2.toUTCString();
    console.log(utcDate2);          // 2017-11-10T05:45:36.000Z
    console.log(utcDateString2);    // Fri, 10 Nov 2017 05:45:36 GMT

    // Get UTC Date
    var dt2 = utcDate2.toISOString().split('T')[0]
    dateArr.push(dt2)
    console.log(dt2); // 2017-11-10

    return dateArr;
}

// Inputs
var inputDateString1 = "Fri Nov 10 05:45:36 +0000 2017";
var inputDateString2 = "Mon May 14 23:59:36 +0000 2018";

var dateArr1 = getMyUTCDate(inputDateString1);
var dateArr2 = getMyUTCDate(inputDateString2);

// Print dates
console.log(dateArr1); // [ '2017-11-10', '2017-11-10' ]
console.log(dateArr2); // [ '2018-05-15', '2018-05-14' ]
```

### References

[developer.mozilla.org - Date processing functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Thanks.